# cloud endpoints slower than rpc, but not with DevAppServer

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

My android app is accessing just a single object (each containing a couple of short lists) from Objectify, but I'm getting delays of up to 15 seconds. I never get such delays using rpc in my web app to get the same objects, nor when I access the blobstore, either with android or a browser app. I thought this could be related to JSON parsing as discussed here : [JSON parsing very slow in Google Cloud Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041878/json-parsing-very-slow-in-google-cloud-endpoints) but in that case we'd expect similar delays with the DevAppServer wouldn't we ?

Here's the endpoints code in the GAE app:

The Endpoint class is based on that auto-generated by GPE, minus all JDO/JPA related code

```
@Api(name = "myclassendpoint",namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "timmacp.com",ownerName = "timmacp.com", packagePath = "endpoints_in_android_app"))
public class MyClassEndpoint {

@ApiMethod(name = "getMyClassObjectByID")
public MyClass getMyClassObjectByID(@Named("id") String id) {

    MyClass object=ofy().load().type(MyClass.class)     
                    .id(EndpointUtils.URLdecode(id)).get();
    return object;
}
```

In the android app, I create a new EndpointsTask (extends AsyncTask) for each button press
& all calls to Endpoint class are in doInBackground(..) called via execute().

First create the endpoint:

```
    MyClassendpoint endpoint;

    MyClassendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new MyClassendpoint.Builder(
            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory(),
            new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
                }
            });

    endpointBuilder=CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder);
    endpoint =endpointBuilder.build();
```

Then test with:

```
endpoint.getMyClassObjectByID("object1").execute();
```

Comment: By RPC in web app, do you mean still accessing via an Endpoints API, or do you mean using your own custom RPCs?

Comment: @saiyr Thanks for your interest. Its an RPC written in GWT, which compiles into Javascript. Its standard way to access Objectify objects in GWT, no endpoints api

Comment: If you happen to have a test Endpoints call that demonstrated the slowness, that could be helpful!

Comment: @saiyr Here's the code. I tested this again today and now only the first call to get an object is slow, and this is consistent. 2 days ago I was getting long delays for maybe 25% of calls, yet blobstore calls were reliably fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this thread for more information:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/3XGJFaosX9s

We are working on eliminating the need for warm-up (i.e. the first request to your API will cause the warm-up to be

Comment: thanks for clarifying this Jun. Can you mark me up for drawing attention to this issue please? I need the points!